# Grouping data within a for loop

Tags: python, loops, grouping

I need to loop over a dataset which is sorted, grouping all the results by that sorted attribute into chunks which all have the same value for that attribute. Then I run some operations on that chunk of results.

Sorry that's a bit confusing, examples are probably a better way of describing what I'm doing:

I've got a dataset that's structured like this except the "data" strings are actually objects and contain plenty of other data.

```
[ [1, "data1"], [1, "data2"], [2, "moredata"], [2, "stuff"], 
  [2, "things"], [2, "foo"], [3, "bar"], [4, "baz"] ]
```

What I want to happen is for that data to get grouped into 4 different function calls:

```
process_data(1, ["data1", "data2"])
process_data(2, ["moredata", "stuff", "things", "foo"])
process_data(3, ["bar"])
process_data(4, ["baz"])
```

What I end up with is a construct that looks something like this:

```
last_id = None
grouped_data = []

for row in dataset:
    id = row[0]
    data = row[1]

    if last_id != id:
         # we're starting a new group, process the last group
         processs_data(last_id, grouped_data)
         grouped_data = []
    last_id = id
    grouped_data.append(data)

if grouped_data:
    # we're done the loop and we still have a last group of data to process
    # if there was no data in the dataset, grouped_data will still be empty
    # so we won't accidentally process any empty data.
    process_data(last_id, grouped_data)
```

It works, but it seems clumsy. Especially the need to track everything with the last_id variable as well as the second call to process_data after the loop. I'd just like to know if anyone can offer any suggestions for a more elegant/clever solution.

My language of choice is Python, but a general solution is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

itertools.groupby is just what you want:

```
>>> data = [ [1, "data1"], [1, "data2"], [2, "moredata"], [2, "stuff"],
...   [2, "things"], [2, "foo"], [3, "bar"], [4, "baz"] ]
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> def process_data(key, keydata):
...     print key, ':', keydata
...
>>> for key,keydata in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)):
...   process_data(key, [d[1] for d in keydata])
...
1 : ['data1', 'data2']
2 : ['moredata', 'stuff', 'things', 'foo']
3 : ['bar']
4 : ['baz']
```

Pass groupby a sorted list, and a key function on what to group by within each item in the list. You get back a generator of `(key,itemgenerator)` pairs, as shown being passed to my made-up process_data method.

[Added 8 Aug 2023]
I have more details in a pair of blog posts on groupby, starting with [this one](https://thingspython.wordpress.com/2020/10/30/python-groupby-and-an-unusual-restaurant/).

Comment: That's perfect. As always, Python comes with all batteries included, it's just a matter of finding where they are. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction on this!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  Note that this requires that your list already be sorted according to the group key (which your example data is, so I guess it's okay).

Answer (score 3):

You can use MutliDict, for example from [brownie](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Brownie/), or [werkzeug](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Werkzeug/) packages.

```
from brownie.datastructures import MultiDict
data = [ [1, "data1"], [1, "data2"], [2, "moredata"], [2, "stuff"], 
         [2, "things"], [2, "foo"], [3, "bar"], [4, "baz"] ]
for key, keydata in MultiDict(data).iterlists():
    process_data(key, keydata)
```